# Admob stop fake clicks: or don't show ads again if user click on ads

Tags: android, admob, adsense

```
As per google rule if they find fake clicks on ad, your account will suspend.
```

I want to stop if, my enemies try to give fake clicks on ads.

If a person click two times on ads,then until next day do not show ads.

> I have 2 solutions to do this, but both solutions has problems..

1. If user click on ads, Save history in db.
2. if user click on ads, Save history in android preferences.

But if user go in app setting, and clean data, then DB, and app preferences also delete, so he can again click on ads...

So how can i store permanent data if user click on ads?

Any other solution? in admob setting, or any other?

Comment: I think that a fake click is some kind of automated click, that would give hundreds or thousands of clicks to an ad, therefore I wouldn't bother about stopping people from clicking several times on your ads.

Comment: But i am worry about my enemies, e.g: if i want to block someone admob account, so i will click on his ads from different devices, so google will treat it as spam, and admob account will be suspended.. I think!!!

Comment: There are no enemies lurking in the shadows intent on destroying your Admob account. My advice is to spend your effort on your business logic and sleep better at night.

Comment: @AsadRaza could you solve the issue? Really what you asked is necessary.

Answer (score -2):

you can limit showing ads in admob and set it like 1 ad per 1 minute